# How do i set conditions for an IF statement as the game progress through "difficulty"?

Tags: c#

This is code that I wanted to put in my IF statement

```
    public GameObject fallingRockPrefab;
public Vector2 spawnsMinMax;
float randX;
float randY;

//Spawn Positions
Vector2 SpawnPosition;
float nextSpawnTime;

void Update()
{
    if (Time.time > nextSpawnTime)
    {
        float SpawningInBetween = Mathf.Lerp(spawnsMinMax.y, spawnsMinMax.x, Difficulty.GetDifficultyPercent());
        print(SpawningInBetween);
        nextSpawnTime = Time.time + SpawningInBetween;

        randX = Random.Range(-5.6f, 5.6f);
        randY = 5.57f;
        SpawnPosition = new Vector2(randX, randY);
        Instantiate(fallingRockPrefab, SpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

    }

}
```

This is the code from my "Difficulty.GetDifficultyPercent"

```
    public static class Difficulty{
static float secondsToMaxDifficulty = 30;

public static float GetDifficultyPercent()
{
    return Mathf.Clamp01(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad / secondsToMaxDifficulty);
}}
```

I'm planning to make a certain event happen when my game bypass a certain stage of a difficulty as it progress but I just don't know what to put it as.

My guess is this,

if(Time.time > Difficulty(25))

but didn't work.

Comment: There arent any functions named 'Difficulty' in the code sample and there is a class but you cannot 'call' class itself in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(GetDifficultyPercent() > .25f)
```

As wondra pointed out, you cannot call a class directly in C#, and this method returns a value 0..1.

If you want to be able to call this method with a time parameter, you will need to update your method to something like this:

```
public static class Difficulty{
   static float secondsToMaxDifficulty = 30;
   public static float GetDifficultyPercent(float time)
   {
       return Mathf.Clamp01(time / secondsToMaxDifficulty);
   }
}
```

and call it like this:

`if(GetDifficultyPercent(Time.time) > .25f)`

Bear in mind that Time.time returns the amount of time that the application has been running. So once you add the functionality to restart the game, or add in a pause function, or a main menu, you will have to rework your difficulty timer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your approach should more or less work. It seems like there are probably two different situations where you will need to consider difficulty in your game.

1.) Increase/Decrease probability with regards to difficulty.

```
private IEnumerator SpawnFallingRockRoutine()
{
    while (playing)
    {
        float spawnCooldown = Mathf.Lerp(minSpawnRate, maxSpawnRate, Difficulty.GetCurrentDifficulty());
        // spawn falling rock logic
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnCooldown);
    }
}
```

2.) Trigger events only if at a certain difficulty.

```
private IEnumerator EvilMonkeySpawnRoutine()
{
    while (playing)
    {
        float cooldown = 1.0f;
        if (Difficulty.GetCurrentDifficulty() >= evilMonkeyDifficulty)
        {
            // spawn evil monkey
            cooldown = evilMonkeyCooldown;
        }

        yield return cooldown;
     }
}
```

You may also want to change how your Difficulty class works to make it a bit more extendable in your project:

```
public class Difficulty
{
    private static float maxDifficultyTime = 30.0f;
    private static float gameStartTime = 0.0f;
    private static float difficultyIncreaseRate = 1.0f;
    private static float difficultyBump = 0.0f;

    public static void SetStartTime(float time)
    {
        gameStartTime = time;
    }

    // Use if you want to make the game temporarily harder
    public static void BumpUpDifficulty(float increase)
    {
        difficultyBump += increase;
    }

    // Use if you want to make the game temporarily easier
    public static void BumpDownDifficulty(float decrease)
    {
        difficultyBump -= decrease;
    }

    // Gets current difficulty in range of 0.0 - 1.0
    public static float GetCurrentDifficulty()
    {
        return Mathf.Clamp01(GetCurrentDifficultyUnclamped());
    }

    // Get current difficulty in range of min - max
    public static float GetCurrentDifficultyClamped(float minDifficulty, float maxDifficulty)
    {
        return Mathf.Clamp(GetCurrentDifficultyUnclamped(), minDifficulty, maxDifficulty);
    }

    // Gets the raw current difficulty (careful with this one)
    public static float GetCurrentDifficultyUnclamped()
    {
        return difficultyBump + (Time.time - gameStartTime) * (difficultyIncreaseRate / maxDifficultyStartTime);
    }
}
```